# sqlite3.OperationalError:: syntax error when trying to UPDATE

Tags: python, sqlite

> I have been trying to update some values in a sqlite3 table but I am
> having loads of problems with the `sqlite3.OperationalError: near
> "GROUP": syntax error. I have been following the documentation but I
> am not been very successful to correct the error. What I am trying to
> do is to find the all_numbers with a value =0 and updated with the
> max(value)+1 I just need to say that I am new creating databases so
> any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    >     def update_tables(connection): #function to update table
    >     c = connection.cursor() # i have a separated def to create the connection
    >     data = """SELECT id, cps, all_numb FROM all_records""" #this is my column selection
    >     c.execute(data)
    >     rows = (c.fetchall())
    >     # print(rows)
    >     _list = []
    >     for row in rows: # I try to use a python loop to iterate through the rows
    >         id = row[0]
    >         cps = row[1]
    >         all_numb = row[2]
    >         if cps not in _list:
    >             _list.append(cps)
    >             if cps in _list: #here I tried a for loop but it does not work
    >                 sq3 = """UPDATE all_records # this is the update selection
    >                             SET all_numb =(SELECT MAX(all_numb) +1) 
    >                             WHERE cps =cps AND all_numb = 0 

    >                             GROUP BY cps"""
    >                 c.execute(sq3)
    >                 connection.commit()
    >                 c.fetchall()
```

Comment: Your title says "ORDER" but the question and code say "GROUP". Please update one or the other.

Comment: It makes no sense to use `GROUP BY` in an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: `cps = cps` will always be true, what's the point of putting that in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Why is `FROM all_records` even there?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a correlated subquery? Then you need to put the `WHERE` clause in the subquery. And you need to use table aliases so you can distinguish the two instances of `all_records`.

Comment: @Barmar, if I remove BY GROUP, I get another error "sqlite3.OperationalError: misuse of aggregate: MAX()"

Comment: @JohnGordon, that is a typo error. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
UPDATE all_records AS r1
SET all_numb = last_numb + 1
FROM (
    SELECT r2.cps, MAX(r2.all_numb) AS last_numb
    FROM all_records AS r2
    GROUP BY r2.cps
)
WHERE r1.cps = r2.cps AND all_numb = 0
```

See the documentation of [`UPDATE FROM`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from)

I'm not sure why you're doing this in a `for` loop, since you're not using any of the variables in the loop. This updates the entire table at once, so it doesn't need to be in a loop.

Comment: I have change my code as you suggested but I get the error: sqlite3.OperationalError: misuse of aggregate: MAX()

Comment: Maybe it needs to be `MAX(r2.all_numb)`

Comment: ```def update_tables2(connection):
    c = connection.cursor()
    data = """SELECT allelerecordid, capsular_gene, allele_number FROM allele_records"""
    c.execute(data)
    rows = (c.fetchall())
    # print(rows)
    sq3 = """UPDATE allele_records AS r1
             SET allele_number =(SELECT MAX(r2.allele_number) +1 
             FROM allele_records AS r2
             WHERE r1.capsular_gene = r2.capsular_gene
             )
              WHERE allele_number = 0 """
    c.execute(sq3)
    connection.commit()```

Comment: @Barmer, I have posted the whole code, pretty badly as the `` seems not to work. I still get the error of misuse of aggregate: MAX

Comment: I've updated the answer to use SQLite's `UPDATE FROM` syntax.

Comment: Please don't try to put large code blocks in comments.

Comment: It doesn't look like you copied my latest answer.

Comment: I posted that before I saw your answer, just to show the my whole code. I did the suggested modification and it worked. Thanks a lot